# Hide/Show Img UNDER Img

Tags: jquery, html, image, toggle, hide

Overall Goal: One line of icons that when clicked, show images, links, etc.

I'm using Jquery right now to do the whole hide/show thing. However, when I test them one at a time, the image appears below the icon. When I tested them all together in the line, the image goes the left of the icon, pushing the rest of the icons to another line.

What can I do so that when someone clicks on the icon (which is an image itself), the hidden image appears BELOW the whole line of icons?

There are four icons and I have them centered.

```
<center><p>
<a id="BioButton"><img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/Lt4na0jnr/bionew.png">    </a><img id="MyBio" style="display:none;"  src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/ce9na0k4w/bioimage.png">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#BioButton').on("click", function(){
         $('#MyBio').toggle();
      });
   });
</script>
<a href="http://www.britrodriguez.com/music"><img     src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/1QLn5uj1h/musicnew.png" style="width: 188px;     height: 188px;" /></a> 
<a href="http://www.britrodriguez.com/SHOWS"><img     src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/vFQn5uj2h/tournew.png" style="width: 188px; height:     188px;" /></a>
<a href="http://www.britrodriguez.com/BOOK"><img     src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/zOHn5uj3b/booknew.png" style="width: 188px; height:     188px;" /></a>
</center></p>
```

Comment: Please provide us a simple example here http://www.jsfiddle.net :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ndo7ywtk/

Comment: So, that should show the problem. When you click BIO, the bio ing appears next to it, rather than underneath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution. Instead of placing the text image inside the bio link/icon, why not put it in its own container? This way the text will alway show up underneath everything.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ndo7ywtk/3/)

Html:

```
<center>

    <div class="icon-container">
        <a href="http://www.britrodriguez.com/music">
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/1QLn5uj1h/musicnew.png" style="width: 188px; height: 188px;" />
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.britrodriguez.com/SHOWS">
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/vFQn5uj2h/tournew.png" style="width: 188px; height: 188px;" />
        </a>
        <a href="http://www.britrodriguez.com/BOOK">
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/zOHn5uj3b/booknew.png" style="width: 188px; height: 188px;" />
        </a>
        <a id="BioButton">
            <img src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/Lt4na0jnr/bionew.png" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="display-container">
        <img id="MyBio" style="display:none;" src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/ce9na0k4w/bioimage.png" />
    </div>

</center>
```

Css:

```
.icon-container{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#BioButton').on("click", function(){
         $('#MyBio').toggle();
      });  
});
```

Comment: Would this option still work if I made all the icons hide/show images underneath?

Comment: Great! It was my pleasure

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have the div MyBio right under the first image.  Move it at the end of all 4 icons (after the  or just before it).  That should solve your problem.

Move this line after the set of icons..

```
<img id="MyBio" style="display:none;" src="http://static.tumblr.com/6s0fefr/ce9na0k4w/bioimage.png"/>
```